# In WFFM how do I hide the "Global Forms" section?

Tags: wffm

I've recently installed WFFM in my Sitecore instance. During this process I have added a custom folder and some forms to it. 
I have linked my folder under

```
<sites> 
  <marketing formsroot="/sitecore/content/marketing/forms-test-folder" />
</sites>
```

and all looks good in the Insert Wizard, except for the fact that the 'Global Forms', 'Sample Forms' section still is visible. See the image:

[image: Global Forms section still visible]

I have tried to hide it by editing the Sitecore.Forms.config file and removing the reference to the folder

```
<!-- SITES -->
<sites>
  <site name="website">
    <!-- <x:attribute name="formsRoot">{F1F7AAB6-C8CE-422F-A214-F610C109FA63}</x:attribute> -->
  </site>
</sites>
```

But the folder is till shown in the Wizard. I have also searched through the config shown by showconfig.aspx and have not been able to find any other instances of 'formsroot' than my own. I know that I can probably just delete the sample folder and be done with it, but I would rather remove the reference to it, whereever it is defined.

So do anyone know where this folder is ultimately defined?

Answer (score 1):

The sample forms are just installed with the module. They are located at `/sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Sample forms`.

The easiest way to remove them from the list would be to just delete the items from the Sitecore tree. If you didn't want to delete them, you could also set security on the folder so that it deny's read access to the `sitecore/Author` role.

Here is the location in the tree:

[image]

Comment: As I said I know that I can just delete them, but I would rather hide dem. Setting access on the folder will not be enough as some of our Sitecore Editors are admins in the system, overwriting any access restriction. I guess the only option is to delete the folder then =/

Comment: You can always mark the items as hidden.